# Datatable search not working when am giving input type text in jsp table

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatable

I know this may be stupid question but please give me some suggestion to work on this. I have a JSP page where am trying to edit cells after retrieving from database. For editing I have used input type="text". But while applying input type as text it is effecting datatable search filter. Here is the code for table creation:

```
<table id='tbl2' border="2">
       <thead>
        <tr style="font-weight: bold;"><th colspan="7" align="center" >Team Shift Roster</th></tr>
        <tr style="font-weight: bold;"><th>Date/Shift</th> <th>06:00AM - 02:00PM</th> <th>02:00PM - 10:00PM</th> <th>10:00PM - 06:00AM</th> <th width="130px">Weekly Off</th> <th width="130px">General Shift</th> <th></th></tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <%
          if(rs != null){ 
               int row=1;
            while(rs.next()){

                %>
             <tr>

                <td style="font-weight: bold;" >
                <input  style="border:0px; width:100px" name="dd"  id="dd<%=row%>" value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>" readonly /></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>" name="one" id="one<%=row%>"/></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="<%=rs.getString(3)%>" name="two" id="two<%=row%>"/></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:130px" type="text"  value="<%=rs.getString(4)%>" name="thr" id="thr<%=row%>"/></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:90px" type="text"  value="<%=rs.getString(5)%>" name="fr" id="fr<%=row%>"/></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:100px" type="text"  value="<%=rs.getString(6)%>" name="fve" id="fve<%=row%>"/></td>
                <td><input style="border:0px; width:90px" type="button" class="ss" onclick="myFun(<%=row%>)" value="Update"></td>
                </tr>

         <%   row++;  } }
              else { out.println("No Record Found"); }   %>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is onclick function :

```
function myFun(row){
      var v1 = document.getElementById("one"+row).value; 
      var v2 = document.getElementById("two"+row).value; 
      var v3 = document.getElementById("thr"+row).value; 
      var v4 = document.getElementById("fr"+row).value; 
      var v5 = document.getElementById("fve"+row).value; 
      var dd = document.getElementById("dd"+row).value; 
      window.location.href='DCM_UsrShiftUpdt.jsp?v1='+v1+'&v2='+v2+'&v3='+v3+'&v4='+v4+'&v5='+v5+'&dd='+dd;
}
```

And this is datatable function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tbl2').DataTable();
```

} );

Kindly help me.

Comment: To get new values you should refresh your table using `table.draw()` or `table.ajax.reload()` [check this discussion](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41615/refresh-datatable-after-editing-a-row)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have got output. :)